# JQPlot - Make y-axis only integers?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

How can I make a graph in jqplot make all of its ticks at even integer intervals? For example, I have

```
yaxis: {numberTicks:16, min: 0}
```

I'd like to have it so that the chart stretches from 0-15, and if plot points go beyond 15, the chart changes to 0-30. Is this doable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the tickInterval instead of numberTicks, like so:

```
axes:
{
    yaxis:
    {
        tickInterval: 15
    }
}
```

I think this is closest to what you want, but note that having a point close to y=15 will cause the chart to stretch to 30 as well.

Comment: if there is no fixed value at that time how can I show integers only?